# What is going on with the Extrusion?

Tags: modeling, faces

Hi so I am currently creating a Witcher Wolf School Medallion just for fun, However it's decided to do this with the last extrusion. I saved before this happened so I've being unable to fix it.

What is this and is there any way to fix it? I appreciate any help given!

- Gemma

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to activate the Clipping option of the Mirror modifier if you don't want your extrusion to create inner faces, but anyway, I guess if your extrusion was not following the X axis is because the original face was a bit tilted on the Z axis, no?

Comment: I mean, by default your extrusion will follow the face normal, if the face is not aligned to the axis, the extrusion won't be

Answer (score 2):

By default your extrusion will follow the normal of your face, so if your face is slightly tilted on the Z axis it won't follow the Y axis. If you want your extrusion to follow the Y axis, you need to constraint the extrusion: press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, then <kbd>Y</kbd>. Also don't forget to activate the *Clipping* option of the *Mirror* modifier, it will prevent the creation of any inner faces.

[image]